# Swift : Subclassing SlackTextViewController in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, frameworks, tableview

I'm new to swift,building small chat app & I've one question.

How to subclass SlackTextViewController in tableview?

I couldn't find a tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Install Cocoa Pods

Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=009UrLVlAbo

2-Add SLKTextViewController

pod 'SlackTextViewController'

3-Add a Bridging header "objective-c file"

## import "SLKTextViewController.h"

4-subclass the UIviewcontroller to SLKTextViewController

```
import UIKit

class Message: SLKTextViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

5-Run!

Comment: If using Cocoapods, the correct import statement should be `#import "SlackTextViewController/SLKTextViewController.h"`

Answer (score 3):

I had to put this to the top of my class to make the pod 'SlackTextViewController' work. 
And it seems nothing connected to Slack is required in Bridging Header.

```
import UIKit
import SlackTextViewController

class EXMessagingTableViewController: SLKTextViewController {
}
```